# Hooking NtWriteFile with MS Detours

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, detours

I try to hook into **NtWriteFile**. Below you find a stripped version of the code I wrote for a dll. The idea is to load the resulting dll with the withdll.exe of MS Detours. With some debugging I found that MyNtWriteFile gets indeed called but then gets stuck at the point of the original function call (the RealNtWriteFile call). Any hints on why is that are highly appreciated. :)

```
#include "pch.h"

#include<windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <winternl.h>


typedef NTSTATUS(*NtWriteFileFunc)(
    HANDLE FileHandle,
    HANDLE Event,
    PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,
    PVOID ApcContext,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    PVOID Buffer,
    ULONG Length,
    PLARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset,
    PULONG Key
    );


NTSTATUS WINAPI MyNtWriteFile(
    HANDLE           FileHandle,
    HANDLE           Event,
    PIO_APC_ROUTINE  ApcRoutine,
    PVOID            ApcContext,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    PVOID            Buffer,
    ULONG            Length,
    PLARGE_INTEGER   ByteOffset,
    PULONG           Key
)
{
    // Call the original function.
    NtWriteFileFunc RealNtWriteFile = (NtWriteFileFunc)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtWriteFile");
    NTSTATUS tmp = RealNtWriteFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext,
        IoStatusBlock, Buffer, Length, ByteOffset, Key);
    
    return tmp;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID reserved)
{   
    HMODULE hNtdll = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
    
    NtWriteFileFunc RealNtWriteFile = (NtWriteFileFunc)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "NtWriteFile");
    
    LONG error;

    if (DetourIsHelperProcess()) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)RealNtWriteFile, MyNtWriteFile);
        error = DetourTransactionCommit();

        
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)RealNtWriteFile, MyNtWriteFile);
        error = DetourTransactionCommit();
        
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Comment: Deadlock. Don't call `LoadLibrary` inside `MyNtWriteFile` (or any other Win32 function). `LoadLibrary` does so much that it wouldn't surprise me if it tries to write something.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added a ```#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")``` at the beginning now and deleted the ```LoadLibrary``` call. From how I understood things, ```GetModuleHandle``` is okay to use in this context. This is how I got the handle now. Besides that nothing has changed and the problem also remains :/

Comment: @Axalo - here no any deadlock. and can not be in pricip ( even if LoadLibrary call NtWriteFile - which it not doing here)

Comment: @RbMm I wasn't talking about `DllMain`. We have to assume the things that aren't documented. We have to assume that `LoadLibrary` calls `NtWriteFile`. We also have to assume that the mutexes it locks aren't reentrant. If you now call `LoadLibrary` and it calls `NtWriteFile`, due to your hook, you're calling `LoadLibrary` inside `LoadLibrary`. And because the mutexes aren't reentrant, you have a deadlock. That was my thought process. It doesn't matter that you know exactly how `LoadLibrary` is implemented if there are no guarantees made by Microsoft. The implementation can change at any time.

Comment: @Axalo call `LoadLibrary` inside `LoadLibrary` is full ok. nothing not reetrant exist here. and if `LoadLibrary` call `NtWriteFile` ( it really exactly not do it) - wil be infinite recursion (if not check for it) but not hang (deadlock)

Answer (score 2):

call `RealNtWriteFile` is fundamental error. because this lead to infinite reqursive loop. you need use pointer , modified in call `DetourAttach`, for call original function.

at first use static link with ntdll.lib - not need `GetProcAddress`.

than declare ( in x64, in x86 need small additional trick) next variable:

```
EXTERN_C extern PVOID __imp_NtWriteFile;
```

you need change protect of this variable:

```
VirtualProtect(&__imp_NtWriteFile, sizeof(PVOID), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &op);
```

if you detour several function - better first get self IAT section and change protect of all IAT, for not do this several times ( `RtlImageDirectoryEntryToData(&__ImageBase, TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT, &size);` )

and use next call

```
DetourDetach(&__imp_NtWriteFile, MyNtWriteFile);
```

restore protection of _*imp* / IAT ( optional )

and inside `MyNtWriteFile`, if you want call original function - simply call `NtWriteFile` as is.

sense of all this is next - `__imp_NtWriteFile` initially will be hold address of `ntdll!NtWriteFile` ( this do loader )

the `DetourAttach(&__imp_NtWriteFile, myhook)` - set hook in address to which point `__imp_NtWriteFile` and **modify** this pointer (it **Inout** ) parameter. after (success) call `__imp_NtWriteFile` will be point to tramopline ( chunk of memory - where several original bytes or hooked function saved + jmp to function body after this bytes)

and `NtWriteFile` use value stored at variable `__imp_NtWriteFile` for call api. main that api **must** be declared with `__declspec(dllimport)`

this is common - for imported `someapi` used `PVOID __imp_someapi` variable.
if you use delayed import - `__imp_load_someapi` name is used (but not in *x86*)

if by some reason (really not need do this) want not static link to ntdll - anyway declare and **define** in this case

```
EXTERN_C PVOID __imp_NtWriteFile = 0;
```

note, that already variable not `extern` (declared only) but defined.

and you need now direct call `__imp_NtWriteFile = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtWriteFile");`

and now you not need VirtualProtect of course.

for x86 - name is mangled it will be

`__imp__NtWriteFile@36`

unfortunatelly we can not direct use names with `@` symbol in c/c++ code. so possible 2 solution - use asm - in it we can have such names and call `DetourAttach` from asm.

but more simply solution, use `/ALTERNATENAME` linker option.

so use

```
#ifdef _X86_
#pragma comment(linker, "/ALTERNATENAME:___imp_NtWriteFile=__imp__NtWriteFile@36")
#endif
```

in case you static link to ntdll - the variable `__imp__NtWriteFile@36` is exist - it defined by linker. but we can not access it in cpp. instead we use `___imp_NtWriteFile` defined as extern. it not exist and we tell linker use `__imp__NtWriteFile@36`

if you not static link to ntdll, but defined `__imp_NtWriteFile` by self - need inverted declaration

```
#ifdef _X86_
#pragma comment(linker, "/ALTERNATENAME:__imp__NtWriteFile@36=___imp_NtWriteFile")
#endif
```

because in this case already `__imp__NtWriteFile@36` not exist and need use `___imp_NtWriteFile` in it place

---

and what you can do inside hook: of course no sense set hook for only and call original api. so real code will be do something more. and here exist risk or reqursive call - in hook you call some api , and this api indirect again call your hook. for this you need detect reqursive call and in such case - direct call original api, without any extra processing. for this can be used `RtlGetFrame`, `RtlPushFrame`, `RtlPopFrame` or tls. but this is already separare question

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see the problem now but one question remains: you said I can just use ```NtWriteFile``` inside ```MyNtWriteFile```. But since ```NtWriteFile``` is using the value stored at ```__imp__NtWriteFile```, isn't that a loop again?

Comment: @johannes - are you read my answer ? `DetourAttach` is **modify** value of `__imp__NtWriteFile`

Comment: Yes, I did read it. The way I understood it, ```__imp__NtWriteFile``` points to ```MyNtWriteFile``` after the modification.

Comment: @johannes no of course. after `DetourAttach` return - it point to trampoline, which you need call

Comment: @johannes also call to `DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());` is senseless, butnothing affect

Comment: so what I did now in summary:
1. added ```#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")```
2. ```EXTERN_C extern PVOID __imp_NtWriteFile;```
3. ```DWORD op;
    VirtualProtect(&__imp_NtWriteFile, sizeof(PVOID), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &op);```
4. replace ```RealNtWriteFile``` with ```NtWriteFile``` but here it gives me an error saying that it is undefined.
I would like to chat about this but my reputation is only 11 :/

Comment: @johannes and are you define `NtWriteFile` ? you not include *ntifs.h*. so you must define it by self

Comment: yes, I now defined it. But I get the error _unresolved external symbol_.

Comment: @johannes - I don't know how you defined it and which symbol is unresolved. You forget that i not under your monitor. And in all case task required understanding

Comment: I defined it like this: `
``__kernel_entry NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtWriteFile(
    _In_ HANDLE FileHandle,
    _In_opt_ HANDLE Event,
    _In_opt_ PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,
    _In_opt_ PVOID ApcContext,
    _Out_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    _In_reads_bytes_(Length) PVOID Buffer,
    _In_ ULONG Length,
    _In_opt_ PLARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset,
    _In_opt_ PULONG Key
);```

The error is more specific:LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) long __cdecl NtWriteFile(void *,....

Comment: What exactly name of the symbol ? Extern "C" you of course forget?

Comment: Do i need to add ```EXTERN_C``` when defining ```NtWriteFile```?
This is the exact error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) long __cdecl NtWriteFile(void *,void *,void (__cdecl*)(void *,struct _IO_STATUS_BLOCK *,unsigned long),void *,struct _IO_STATUS_BLOCK *,void *,unsigned long,union _LARGE_INTEGER *,unsigned long *)" (__imp_?NtWriteFile@@YAJPEAX0P6AX0PEAU_IO_STATUS_BLOCK@@K@Z010KPEAT_LARGE_INTEGER@@PEAK@Z) referenced in function...

Comment: @johannes of course need. Are you not view ?